# Have a cell static after 1st dynamic update

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am using Google Sheet and fetching data from Google Finance. On checking for a condition 1st time, if it is true, I am filling a cell with "EXIT" and I want this to remain static after 1st fill.
However, since the google finance data is dynamic based on current data, this check condition keeps updating the filled cell with every change.
what I want is to fill this cell for just the first change and then make it static.
How to achieve this?

Comment: You should post your code, or at least the part about updating the cell. From what it sounds like... you want to change a cell, but then make it impossible to change a cell... based on what? Perhaps update your code to check if a cell has a value of Exit? If so, do nothing?

Comment: Please also provide a sample sheet with your expected output. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with traditional Google Sheets formulas and functions.  You will need to learn about google sheets "appscript".  Which is a javascript-like coding language that you can use in the back-end of Google Sheets (Extensions > App Script) to plan and program more complex sheets activities.

If you're not familiar with appScript, you should read about what it is before asking more about how to do this so that you can frame and ask your question appropriately.

Here's a decent primer for learning more about Google AppScript.

https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1#0